# How do I sort my sqlite table according to date and time?

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to sort my table according to the date and time. My database has two seperate columns for both date and time and they are stored as strings dd-MM-yyyy and HH:mm am/pm respectively. How do I sort them so that the latest entry shows at the top?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format of the dates you store in the db is **not comparable**, so you will always have to deal with problems like this. 
Better change the format of the date to `YYYY-MM-DD` and of the time to `hh:mm`. 
In the meantime you can use [`substr()`](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_corefunc.html#substr):

```
select * from tablename
order by 
  substr(datecol, 7) || substr(datecol, 4, 2)  || substr(datecol, 1, 2) DESC, 
  case length(timecol)
    when 8 then substr(timecol, 7) || substr(timecol, 1, 5)
    when 7 then substr('0' || timecol, 7) || substr('0' || timecol, 1, 5)
  end DESC
```

Change `datecol` and `timecol` to the names of your columns.  
This changes the format of the date to `HHHHMMDD` and the time's format to `AM/PM mm:HH` and these will be used only in `ORDER BY`. 
As I mentioned earlier the proper solution would be a permanent change in the formats of the date and time.

Comment: how will substr(timecol, 7) || substr(timecol, 1, 5) DESC help?

Comment: This will convert a date like: `03-05-2019` to `20190503` which is comparable.

Comment: And a time like `11:30 AM` to `AM 11:30`

Comment: the entries are being shown in the following order:
12:00 pm
3:19 pm
12:00 am
7:36 am

while the requirement is:

3:19 pm
12:00 pm
7:36 am
12:00 am

Comment: You said that the format of the time is hh:MM am/pm, but it seems it is not. If you have times like 3:19 pm then there are not 2 digits for hour.

Comment: in the actual table there aren't two digits but I used CASE WHEN LENGTH(time)=8 THEN time ELSE '0'||time END AS NEWTIME for making it like that and used substr(NEWTIME, 7) || substr(NEWTIME, 1, 5) DESC as you suggested.

Comment: Sure bud, take your time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Tried it. Unfortunately gives the same result :(

Comment: Is there a case that the length could be other than 7 or 8? Maybe there are spaces? Try `trim(timecol)` everywhere. And I suppose there is always a space between time and am/pm,

Comment: nope, the length is always 7 or 8. I think the real problem is the fact that 12 is greater than all the other possible hour values but at the same time the smallest value in a time based context. If I was using 24 hour values the story would have been different.

Comment: There should not be a `12:00 pm` but `00:00 am`.

Comment: the time isn't 24-hour. It is 12 hour but I guess I can just convert 12 to 00 and that should solve the problem completely. Thank you so much!

Comment: Exactly, so after `11:59 pm` the next min is `00:00 am`. Post once again a sample of the order of the times in a single day.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following would do as you wish (assuming the table is name **mytable** and the date column is named **the_date** and the time column is named **the_time** (obviously change these values acordingly)) :-

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN (substr(the_date,2,1) = '-') AND (substr(the_date,4,1) = '-') THEN substr(the_date,5,4)||'0'||substr(the_date,3,1)||'0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
        WHEN substr(the_date,2,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||substr(the_date,3,2)||'0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
        WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||'0'||substr(the_date,4,1)||substr(the_date,1,2)
      WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,6,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,7,4)||substr(the_date,4,2)||substr(the_date,1,2)
    END DESC
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||'0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||substr(the_time,3,2)  
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||'0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||substr(the_time,3,2)       
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||'0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||substr(the_time,4,2)       
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||'0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||substr(the_time,4,2)
    END DESC
;
```

This will handle all permutations of single or double digits for day of the month, month of the year, hours and minutes.

It doesn't care about **12:00 pm** this resolves to 24:00 (that is when **pm** is coded the hour has 12 added to it (so even 32:00 pm would be converted (as such) and be considered as hour 44)). 00:00 pm would be the same as 12:00 am (as 12 is added to the hour).

The above was tested using :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mytable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (the_description TEXT, the_date TEXT, the_time TEXT);
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES
    ('REC001','1-1-2019','1:15 am'),
    ('REC002','11-2-2019','11:15 am'),
    ('REC003','2-11-2019','1:15 pm'),
    ('REC004','12-10-2019','11:15 pm'),
    ('REC005','3-2-2019','12:00 am'),
    ('REC006','4-3-2018','12:00 pm'),
    ('REC007','4-3-2018','12:1 am'),
    ('REC008','4-3-2018','1:1 pm')

;
SELECT * FROM mytable;
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN substr(the_date,2,1) = '-' AND (substr(the_date,4,1) = '-') THEN substr(the_date,5,4)||'0'||substr(the_date,3,1)||'0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
        WHEN substr(the_date,2,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||substr(the_date,3,2)||'0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
        WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||'0'||substr(the_date,4,1)||substr(the_date,1,2)
      WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,6,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,7,4)||substr(the_date,4,2)||substr(the_date,1,2)
    END AS SORTdate,
    CASE
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||'0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||substr(the_time,3,2)  
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||'0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||substr(the_time,3,2)       
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||'0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||substr(the_time,4,2)       
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||'0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||substr(the_time,4,2)
    END AS sorttime
FROM mytable 
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN (substr(the_date,2,1) = '-') AND (substr(the_date,4,1) = '-') THEN substr(the_date,5,4)||'0'||substr(the_date,3,1)||'0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
        WHEN substr(the_date,2,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||substr(the_date,3,2)||'0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
        WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||'0'||substr(the_date,4,1)||substr(the_date,1,2)
      WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,6,1) = '-' THEN substr(the_date,7,4)||substr(the_date,4,2)||substr(the_date,1,2)
    END DESC
    ,
    CASE
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||'0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||substr(the_time,3,2)  
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||'0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||substr(the_time,3,2)       
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||'0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' am') THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||substr(the_time,4,2)       
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||'0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
        WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' pm') THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||substr(the_time,4,2)
    END DESC
;
```

#### Unsorted rows as initially loaded :-

[image]

#### Sorted rows with the sort order fields (converted dates and times) displayed:-

[image]

## Additional

If the dates were stored using YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM (or any of the recognised formats [Date And Time Functions - Time Strings](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)) then you'd just sort on the column (only 1 column would be needed). It is very simple to also extract data in many formats.

The following is an example of a mass update that will convert the two columns to a single column from the d(d)-m(m)-yyyy  and the h(h):m(m) format (where bracketed values may or may not exist depending upon the whether the value has a number of tens or not). In the example both columns **the_date** and **the_time** are converted :-

```
WITH cte1(cte1id,date,time) AS
    (
        SELECT rowid,
            CASE 
                WHEN substr(the_date,2,1) = '-' AND (substr(the_date,4,1) = '-') 
                    THEN substr(the_date,5,4)||'-0'||substr(the_date,3,1)||'-0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
                WHEN substr(the_date,2,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' 
                    THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||'-'||substr(the_date,3,2)||'-0'||substr(the_date,1,1)
                WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,5,1) = '-' 
                    THEN substr(the_date,6,4)||'-0'||substr(the_date,4,1)||'-'||substr(the_date,1,2)
                WHEN substr(the_date,3,1) = '-' AND substr(the_date,6,1) = '-' 
                    THEN substr(the_date,7,4)||'-'||substr(the_date,4,2)||'-'||substr(the_date,1,2)
            END AS date,
            CASE
                WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' am') 
                    THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||':0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
                WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') 
                    THEN '0'||substr(the_time,1,1)||':'||substr(the_time,3,2)   
                WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 4 AND instr(the_time,' pm') 
                    THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||':0'||substr(the_time,3,1)
                WHEN substr(the_time,2,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') 
                    THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,1) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||':'||substr(the_time,3,2)        
                WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' am') 
                    THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||':0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
                WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' am') 
                    THEN substr(the_time,1,2)||':'||substr(the_time,4,2)        
                WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 5 AND instr(the_time,' pm') 
                    THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||':0'||substr(the_time,4,1)
                WHEN substr(the_time,3,1) = ':' AND instr(the_time,' ') = 6 AND instr(the_time,' pm') 
                    THEN CAST(12 + CAST(substr(the_time,1,2) AS INTEGER) AS TEXT)||':'||substr(the_time,4,2)
            END AS time
        FROM mytable 
        )
UPDATE mytable 
    SET 
        the_date = (SELECT date||' '||time FROM cte1 WHERE cte1id = mytable.rowid),
        the_time = (SELECT date||' '||time FROM cte1 WHERE cte1id = mytable.rowid)
;
```

The following shows how much simpler the query then becomes, additionally how to retrieve the date and time close to the original format (times are not am pm) from the converted table :-

```
SELECT 
    strftime('%d-%m-%Y %H:%M',the_date) AS old_format, -- Close to original format
    * FROM mytable ORDER BY the_date DESC; -- much simpler to sort
```

The result being :-

[image]

- column **old_format** is the date close to the original format (but 24hr)
- as can be seen columns **the_date** and **the_time** have been converted to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM format and as such the sorting with the latest first is simply a matter of sorting by the column (either) in descending order.
- Selecting a range of dates is also very simple using such a format e.g. `WHERE the_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-03-31'` would select just the 3 rows that are in the first 3 months of 2019 (from the rows as above).